# ¿Cómo ejecutar un segundo activity en android después de leer un código qr?

Tags: android

tengo un problema al momento de lanzar la segunda actividad en android, pues tengo un programa que lee códigos qr, y en esta sentencia tengo lo siguiente

```
if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(token)) { //token contiene la lectura del código
      Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
      Uri.parse(token));
      startActivity(browserIntent);
      //esta parte funciona correcto
  } else {

      try{
          Intent act2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
          startActivity(act2);
          //esta parte no funciona, ni entra al catch, se cierra la app
      }
      catch (Exception e){
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
          e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
}
```

Ayuda por favor.
Gracias.

Comment: Y cual es el problema en si?

Answer (score 1):

No va a entrar a al bloque que deseas puesto que si el código es correcto solo ejecutara el bloque `if`:

```
  if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(token)) { //token contiene la lectura del código
     ... 
     //Código QR correcto.
     ...
  } else {
     ... 
     //Código QR incorrecto.
     ...  
 }
```

si deseas se llame la Activity siempre que realices la lectura del código QR simplemente llama el intent afuera del if:

```
if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(token)) { //token contiene la lectura del código
      Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
      Uri.parse(token));
      startActivity(browserIntent);
      //esta parte funciona correcto
} 

 try{
     Intent act2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
     startActivity(act2);
     //esta parte no funciona, ni entra al catch, se cierra la app
 }catch (Exception e){
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```